# Do I have to run the training data each time I update json intent file?

Tags: python, nltk, chatbot, nltk-trainer

I have created a chatbot using NLTK. I'm trying to perfect my responses, but each time I amend my json intent file, I know no other way but to reinput it by running the training data file.

Is there another way?

Regards
Pav